# Postfix: Rewrite mail destination address before delivering mail

Tags: email, postfix

I'm a little stuck on implementation of things here in Postfix, because we're trying to replace a sendmail email gateway/relay with Postfix, and replicate the setup.

Currently, the sendmail gateway does several things:

(1) Handles splitting of traffic destinations so things go to specific endpoint mail servers.  That is, `foo@domain.tld` would be sent to `imap01.domain.tld` by Sendmail.  `foobar@domain.tld`, a listserv, would be relayed to `relay01.domain.tld` which is the ListServ system for relaying ListServ mail.

(2) Handles certain other domains and delivers them to the proper endpoints for those domains, whether they be email addresses sitting on `exchange01`, or local alias lists, or other servers.

(3) All other `@domain.tld` mail would first be rewritten to be `address@pa.domain.tld`, which is then delivered to `exchange01.domain.tld`.

Now, this works great in SendMail, but SendMail is a royal pain to try and configure and modify configuration settings for.  As such, we're trying to move to PostFix.

From PostFix, I've got mail properly relaying via transport maps for the individual email addresses that need customized routing, but I'm having issues with the third part, rewriting the domain before delivering it to the `exchange01` server.

Anyone got any guidance for what I need to change in Postfix to do the third part of what that sendmail gateway currently does?  (There's an MX record for `pa.domain.tld` interally, if it matters, which points to `exchange01`, I just need to figure out the rewriting functionality before specifying an `@pa.domain.tld` record in `/etc/postfix/transport`.)

This is Postfix 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, if it matters, but I'd like to have a solution that isn't dependent on Ubuntu-only items.

> Editors: Please do not add the [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) tag, I left it off intentionally.

Comment: Maybe this might be able to help you: [Address rewriting postfix official doc](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html)

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I looked there, but it wasn't clear where canonical maps (which probably would work) come into play - before or after the transport mechanism.  If it's before the transport mechanism then it'll break some things; if it's after the transport mechanism, then I *might* be able to make it work, except for the Exchange delivery...